# Why is my text size so small after changing my screen magnification to 125% and back?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dpi

I recently changed my screen magnification to "Medium - 125%" in Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Display, to test it out. I logged out and logged back in, and it worked. I didn't like it, so I changed the setting back to the default value of "Smaller - 100%". I logged out and logged back in again.

Now, my DPI seems broken. My taskbar seems to have the correct height, windows are the right size, and so on. However, my text font is much smaller than it used to be. The text in the title bars of programs, text in right-click menus, and a lot of text within program windows is much smaller than it used to be. Logging out and restarting my computer does nothing to help the issue.

I have checked the LogPixels value in the registry, and it is set to 96. What's the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a [System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) to a point before you started making hte DPI changes?

Comment: @Psycogeek Refreshing the theme fixed it. Thanks! If you post that as an answer then I could accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most of the items you mentioned are also controlled by themes, The font sizes for the Operating systems title bars, and menues and all. Try Changing the theme  in the control pannel personalisation themes, even if you change it right back to the theme you were on.

---

We Also had some specific Programs, that did not respond correctally to the Windows 7 DPI change, One program when I put the DPI up, the text got really small. ? If it is any aspects of the OS itself and not program specific, "refresh your theme" , go to personalise themes and change the theme to another one, just as a starting point. Run a refresh on the desktop too.

The DPI setting should not change between themes, but the font used and font sizes can. in XP One location for theme font size changing (quick) in "Display properties" [Apperances] tab "Font size". Then save your "modified theme". . In the same location the "advanced" button will allow you to adjust most of the various font and sizes, even when themed. OKing and APPLYing to be able to see the changes. Even with all the change locations, there will be some things that are locked in size, as thier windows and format is also locked, and 96DPI will still be small for those few things.

In WIN7 the location is Different, in the personalisation section, and Called "windows Color" In the AERO interface you have to go to the Windows color, then the "advanced apperance settings" at the bottom of windows color

Comment: Thank you! My title bars and Firefox address bar were tiny after changing my DPI to 96. If I switch back to my "unsaved theme" it goes tiny again so not sure how to actually change it for the theme, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display->Set custom text size (DPI)**

Create a custom DPI of 101%. Apply this text size and log off. Log back in and go back to the original 100%. Then after logging back on your font size should be fixed.

PS. for me, the other solution did not work, but this one did