# Windows 7 DPI is behaving crazily

Tags: windows-7, dpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my text size so small after changing my screen magnification to 125% and back?](https://superuser.com/questions/357291/why-is-my-text-size-so-small-after-changing-my-screen-magnification-to-125-and)

I'm experimenting with DPI settings.

When I set it to 150% it is fine. Everything is 150% as it is supposed to be.

But when I reset it to 100%, some menus (context menus and most programs' menus) become too small!

[image: What the hell]

As you can see, the font size on the context menu is too small. Should be the same size as the fonts on the desktop.

This is really annoying, I cant reset it back to default. I tried to set to 150%, back to 100%. The result is the same. On 100%, the fonts are too small on context menus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. Switched the windows them to classic, deleted my custom theme and than switched to default windows aero, and customized that.

Comment: Unfortunately this means that I had to ditch my custom theme. I wonder if there are any built in ways to modify those aspects of the custom theme. I'm guessing these things are all stored in the registry.