# How to reset Windows' default font size for titles and text fields?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

A few days ago, I changed my display size to 150% using the Control Panel (Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display). It worked perfectly, and I changed it back to 100%. Now, all the window titles, tab titles, and a few other things are in a 7pt-ish font size (see link below).

I have checked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/357291/why-is-my-text-size-so-small-after-changing-my-screen-magnification-to-125-and) and tried [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html), with no success. My DPI as seen in the Windows registry is 96, which is the normal value. My settings in the Window Color and Appearance dialog box are set to Segoe UI, font size 9, which is obviously not the used font size.

How do I get back the normal font sizes?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

*Notice the Opera tab titles, all the window titles and most non-editable elements in Android Studio.*

Answer (score 1):

Re-apply the default theme, instead of changing the appearance settings individually. Else, if that doesn't work, try using [this reset bat file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/309079d1394013154-advanced-appearance-settings-backup-restore-windows-backup_advanced_appearance_settings.bat). This will re-write the associated Windows registry data that is stored for the current windows appearance and theme settings, etc.